# Linux Kernel symbol addresses don't match between /proc/kcore and /proc/kallsyms

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, gdb

For some reason, the addresses I get from /proc/kallsyms and the one I get debugging the running kernel using /proc/kcore are different.

```
# uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Sep 26 15:12:11 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# rpm -ql kernel-debuginfo-3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64 | grep vmlinux
/usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64/vmlinux

# gdb -q /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64/vmlinux /proc/kcore
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64/vmlinux...done.
[New process 1]
Core was generated by `BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/centos-root ro c'.
#0  0x0000000000000000 in irq_stack_union ()

(gdb) p &init_task
$1 = (struct task_struct *) 0xffffffff81c16480 <init_task>
(gdb) quit

# grep "D init_task" /proc/kallsyms 
ffffffffa0a16480 D init_task
```

Both addresses are, of course, from the same machine without rebooting it.

Shouldn't be the addresses match? Why that shift ?

0xffffffff**81c1**6480

0xffffffff**a0a1**6480

Comment: I think this is the effect of [Kernel Address Space Layout Randomization (KASLR)](https://lwn.net/Articles/569635/). You can use the `-s /proc/kallsyms` gdb parameters to use the live kernel symbols.

Comment: AFAIK both /proc/kcore and /proc/kallsyms should be updated with the real (relocated) addresses, so it shouldn't be a KASLR effect.

Comment: Plus /proc/kallsyms isn't an ELF file, so it won't work with -s.

Comment: You are correct that `-s /proc/kallsyms` won't work because it is the wrong format. You are partially correct about `/proc/kcore` and `/proc/kallsyms` being updated, but note that `/proc/kcore` contains no symbol table. Why do you think it is not a KASLR effect?

Comment: Note that GDB 8.2 has an option to load a symbol file with an offset (but I think it can only be specified for the GDB `add-symbol-file` command, not in the GDB invocation command-line parameters). This may be useful for debugging the live kernel once the KASLR offset has been determined (e.g. by comparing the symbols from vmlinux with those in /proc/kallsyms).

Comment: Yeah, the symbols are taken from a vmlinux with debug symbols. I thought that gdb takes some information from the running kernel using kcore to figure out the offset, but apparently it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up disabling *KASLR* adding the **nokaslr** parameter to the kernel command line.

However, even with *KASLR* disabled, it's still needed to fix the symbol offsets. As @Ian suggested in one of the comments, I used the *gdb* **add-symbol-file** command. Loading the symbols using the offset of the **text** address, as follows:

```
# grep "D init_task" /proc/kallsyms
ffffffff81c16480 D init_task

# grep " _text" /proc/kallsyms
ffffffff81000000 T _text

# gdb -q -c /proc/kcore
(gdb) add-symbol-file /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64/vmlinux 0xffffffff81000000
add symbol table from file "/usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64/vmlinux" at
    .text_addr = 0x81000000
(y or n) y
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/modules/3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64/vmlinux...done.

(gdb) p &init_task
$1 = (struct task_struct *) 0xffffffff81c16480 <init_task>
```

It works with **gdb 7.6.1**.

Anyway, it will be fantastic to know how to do it with KASLR enable.

Comment: The `crash` utility (built on top of gdb) can handle kernels with kaslr enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that `init_task` is in the DATA segment.

```
# grep -w init_task /proc/kallsyms
ffffffffbb0134c0 D init_task
```

So first you need to find the start address of your kernel's data segment, which is the address of the `_sdata` symbol in `/proc/kallsyms`.

```
# grep -w _sdata /proc/kallsyms
ffffffffbb000000 D _sdata
```

Then if you load your vmlinux with the right address of the data segment it will work even with KASLR enabled.

```
# gdb -q -c /proc/kcore
(gdb) add-symbol-file /usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-4.12.14-122.37-default.debug -s .data 0xffffffffbb000000
add symbol table from file "/usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-4.12.14-122.37-default.debug" at
        .data_addr = 0xffffffffbb000000
(y or n) y
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-4.12.14-122.37-default.debug...
(gdb) p &init_task
$1 = (struct task_struct *) 0xffffffffbb0134c0 <init_task>
```

And - voila, now the address of `init_task` is `0xffffffffbb0134c0`, which is exactly what you see in `/proc/kallsyms`.